# How to have 2 or more canvas in the same page.. not as layers

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a page where I've 2 canvas. 
One for **tracking mouse position** and another for **simple drawing**. Both the code are working but not as expected.

1. Both the canvas got pushed down..
2. Displays both the canvas but
3. Uses only one of the canvas to display the results

. Why?? Here is the link to my page [Canvas](http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/portfolio_html5/canvas5.html), 
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKQNu.png)

Comment: So you want both canvas elements to display the same thing? Im not clear on issue #3

Comment: Nope. One canvas to display the Tracking Mouse Position's result other one for displaying the Simple Canvas Drawing.

Comment: are you saying that you'll use one canvas for drawing(as track pad) and the other canvas to display the outcome(display)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were appending both canvas elements each time. Heres the area of code that does it, and a quick check i put in place.

```
if(flag ===1){
    canvasDiv1.appendChild(canvas);
}else{
    canvasDiv2.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

Here is a link to the full code, and what I assume you were going for.

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/R3hyg/

Comment: I guess after rereading your question the above only addresses issue 1.